# Filter ArrayList from a Database

Tags: java, android, arrays, filter

I want to filter an `ArrayList` with a value from a Database.

Here is my filter code were I create and "filter" the adapter:

```
// Inicializar adaptador
Log.d("DIATX", String.valueOf(8));
for(int i=0;i<metas.size();i++){
     if(metas.getObject(i).miId != null){
          filteredArr.put(metas.getObject(i));
     }
}
adapter = new MetaAdapter_Asistencia(Arrays.asList(metas), getActivity(), myId);
// Setear adaptador a la lista
lista.setAdapter(adapter);
progressBar_first.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

The main problem of this is that I'm getting this error: Cannot resolve method 'getObject(int)' and with size. Is there another way to filter my Array? Thanks in avance for answering.

This is my code before creating the array:

```
public void cargarAdaptador() {
    VolleySingleton.getInstance(getActivity()).addToRequestQueue(
        new JsonObjectRequest(
             Request.Method.GET,
             Constantes.GET_Asistencia,
             null,
             new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                 @Override
                 public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                     // Procesar la respuesta Json
                     procesarRespuesta(response);
                 }
             },
             new Response.ErrorListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                     Log.d(TAG, "Error Volley: " + error.toString());
                 }
             }
        )
    );
}
public void procesarRespuesta(JSONObject response) {
    try {
        // Obtener atributo "estado"
        String estado = response.getString("estado");
        switch (estado) {
            case "1": // EXITO
            // Obtener array "metas" Json
            JSONArray mensaje = response.getJSONArray("metas");

            Meta_Asistencia[] metas = gson.fromJson(mensaje.toString(), Meta_Asistencia[].class);

            // APLICACIÓN DE ORDEN:
            // Ordenar el array de metas por idMeta de forma descendente:
            Arrays.sort(metas, new Comparator<Meta_Asistencia>() {
                int result;
                DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);

            @Override
            public int compare(Meta_Asistencia objeto1, Meta_Asistencia objeto2) {
                // Comparamos por fechaLim de forma descendente:
                try {
                    result = f.parse(objeto2.dia).compareTo(f.parse(objeto1.dia));
                    Log.d("DIA", objeto1.dia);
                    Log.d("DIA1", objeto2.dia);
                    Log.d("ordenar", String.valueOf(result));
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return result;
            }
        });

        // Inicializar adaptador
        for(int i=0;i<metas.size();i++){
             if(metas.getObject(i).miId != null){
                  filteredArr.put(metas.getObject(i));
             }
        }
        adapter = new MetaAdapter_Asistencia(Arrays.asList(metas), getActivity());
        // Setear adaptador a la lista
        lista.setAdapter(adapter);
        progressBar_first.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

miidf1 are the 4 id's of the elements of my database
So herer's my filter code:

```
                Log.d("miidf", myId);
                for(int i=0;i<metas.length;i++){
                    Log.d("miidf1", String.valueOf(metas[i].getId_musico()));
                    if(metas[i].getId() != null && 
                        metas[i].getId_musico().equals(myId)){

                        filteredArr.put(metas[i]);
                    }

                }
```

And the Log

```
2018-10-13 21:14:57.510 27007-27007/app.bsmo.ismael034.com.bsmo D/miidf: 2
2018-10-13 21:14:57.511 27007-27007/app.bsmo.ismael034.com.bsmo D/miidf1: 2
2018-10-13 21:14:57.511 27007-27007/app.bsmo.ismael034.com.bsmo D/miidf1: 2
2018-10-13 21:14:57.511 27007-27007/app.bsmo.ismael034.com.bsmo D/miidf1: 3
2018-10-13 21:14:57.512 27007-27007/app.bsmo.ismael034.com.bsmo D/miidf1: 4
```

So its comparing well(I think) but it show all in my screen, so maybe it doesnt showing because its not passed to the adapter, but, how?

Comment: Whats the type of metas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The case you shared shows that **metas** is an array.

> Meta_Asistencia[] metas = gson.fromJson(mensaje.toString(), Meta_Asistencia[].class);

You can't use .size() method on array, neither you can **get** an array object by **getObject(i)**.

Here are two changed you need to make in your for-loop:

1. Replace **size()** with **length**
2. Replace **.getObject(i)** with **[i]**

Hence your final code should look like this:

```
  for(int i=0;i<metas.length;i++){
               if(metas[i].miId != null && metas[i].miId == 2){
                  filteredArr.put(metas[i]);
  }
```

I hope this solves your problem.
Cheers!

Comment: It works but, how to pass this into the adapter and only show me the filtered options? Thanks

Comment: On what basis are you wanting the metas array to be filtered?

Comment: I want to filter from a variable from other activity, for example the database send me 4 items, with 1,2,2 and 1, for example I only want to show the elements that have two

Comment: Okay, I've modified the for-loop for the ID filteration. I hope that would work for you!

Comment: Updated my answer, see the end. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`Metas` is an array not the list, you need to modify your code like below

```
for(int i=0;i<metas.length;i++){
    if(metas[i].miId != null){
        filteredArr.put(metas[i]);
    }
    /*if(metas[i].getObject().miId != null){
        filteredArr.put(metas[i].getObject());
    }*/
}
```

Comment: Yes, it doesnt sow any error but, how to pass this into the adapter and only show me the filtered options? Thanks